# Storing only changed files in Git when using a framework e.g. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, git, cakephp, frameworks

I regularly use Laravel to build applications. Recently, I have started using Lumen to build microservices.

One thing I notice with Lumen, is that I often only need to create 2-3 files, and edit a further 2-3 (providers, configs and routes). In total, I am editing or creating 5-6 files.

It feels to me that my git repositories for these microservices would be way cleaner if they only included the changed files, and then I merged with the Lumen framework during the CI build/deploy.

Does anyone have any experience with doing this? What are the pros/cons?

Comment: the framework is in vendor .. are you referring to the skeleton project? everything that isn't in vendor is your app technically

Comment: I am referring to the skeleton project, yes. There are lots of files which are essential for the app to run but do not need any modification by me. I could in theory add a `composer create-project` step to my deployment and pull them all from the package repo.

Comment: if you could lock it to the exact version you originally used with `create-project`, run that without pulling the dependencies... then you would have to copy over your composer.json and lock file for your actual dependencies run composer install, then merge stuff

Answer (score 0):

I build many API services with Lumen, and I always have the entire project on git repo, and when I make changes locally, I pushed it to GitHub and from the server i just take a pull. I wouldn't say there are necessarily pros or cons, just different ways of doing things